# Are immutable objects published after they are fully initialized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, immutability

I am reading about immutable objects and thread safety in *Java Concurrency Guidelines* by Fred Long.

Here is a code snippet from the book.

```
// Immutable Helper
public final class Helper {
    private final int n;

    public Helper(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    // ...
}

// and a mutable Foo class:
final class Foo {
    private Helper helper;

    public Helper getHelper() {
        return helper;
    }

    public void setHelper(int num) {
        helper = new Helper(num);
    }
}
```

The code snippet is followed by the explanation:

> The getHelper() method publishes the mutable helper field. Because the
>   Helper class is immutable, it cannot be changed after it is
>   initialized. Furthermore, **because Helper is immutable, it is always
>   constructed properly before its reference is made visible** in
>   compliance with guideline “TSM03-J. Do not publish partially
>   initialized objects” on page 162.

Now let's open page 162 they've mentioned. Here is another code snippet.

```
class Foo {
    private Helper helper;

    public Helper getHelper() {
        return helper;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        helper = new Helper(42);
    }
}

public class Helper {
    private int n;

    public Helper(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

}
```

It's followed by its own explanation:

> If a thread accesses helper using the getHelper() method before the
>   initialize() method has been called, the thread will observe an
>   uninitialized helper field. Later, if one thread calls initialize()
>   and another calls getHelper(), the second thread might observe one of
>   the following:
>
> - the helper reference as NULL,
> - a fully initialized Helper object with the n field set to 42,
> - **a partially initialized Helper object** with an uninitialized n that contains the default value 0.

So don't the two statements I made bold, contradict each other?

---

A wrote a piece of code to test the case, ran it a few times, and never got 0. Only null or 42. Here is my code:

```
package com.sample;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            Initer initer = new Initer(foo);
            Getter getter = new Getter(foo);
            initer.start();
            getter.start();
        }
    }

    static class Getter extends Thread {

        private Foo foo;

        Getter(Foo foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(foo.getHelper());
        }
    }

    static class Initer extends Thread {

        private Foo foo;

        Initer(Foo foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo.initialize();
        }
    }

    static class Foo {
        private Helper helper;

        public Helper getHelper() {
            return helper;
        }

        public void initialize() {
            helper = new Helper(42);
        }
    }

    public static class Helper {
        private int n;

        public Helper(int n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(n);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements are not inconsistent.  If the first example the field `n` is `final`.  This is what makes the `Helper` class immutable.  In the second example, `n` is not final, `Helper` is not immutable, which means a partially initialized instance could be returned.

As far as observing this with your code, Peter is right, it is difficult to test in practice for several reasons.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the final/non-final difference

Answer (score 1):

Unless the field is `final` there is no guarantee the value will be visible however,

- there is no guarantee that it won't.
- you are more likely to see this problem once the code has warmed up i.e. well after 10,000 iterations.
- you are using `println` which has it's own memory barriers which will make it harder to see any inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks. But what about my question? Don't the two statements I made bold, contradict each other?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev in the first example, the field is `final`, in the second it is not.  In this case, it makes all the difference.